# What do cambras and coolers mean here?

Tags: meaning

[image]
What are cambras and coolers in paragraph 3? This device is used for Sous Vide Cooking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That word is "Cambros" and refers to products made by the restaurant supply company [Cambro](http://www.webstaurantstore.com/vendor/cambro.html?gclid=CjwKEAiAp_WyBRD37bGB_ZO9qAYSJAA72IkgndclAJs3SYi0fsvdIIEfMKLagLROdv0NjboJAALyaBoCfE3w_wcB)

A cooler likely refers to an insulated container (typically used to keep cold items cold).

(It might be better to ask this on the cooking SE site.)